# How to enter a train?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I'm able to successfully board a train by dropping down from overhanging platforms, but even once I have worked my way to the front of the train the "enter vehicle" button fails to work.

How do I enter the train so I can control it?

Comment: it's a bug to enter into the train cockpit but that's that have a look at this video : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEH6Im-SOuo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't enter the train to drive it. There is a mission with Trevor in which you get the train and drive it, but outside of that in the open world, it's not possible.

Comment: I miss the train driver missions from *GTA San Andreas* :(

Comment: @Nolonar I miss stealing the train/tram in GTA1 or gta2, and just driving around in circles evading the cops ;)

Comment: I have died too many times trying to board a moving train...